# Updating Related Model (foreign key) in Laravel & Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, fluent

There are two tables, `Language` & `Text` with a one-to-many relationship where the `Text` receives foreign key of `Language` table.

I have set up models & relationships properly & the retrieval of models works just fine.

How can I associate `Language` entity to certain existing `Text` records.

I have tried fetching some `Text` records and inserting them into `Language` using

```
$language = Language::find(1);
$textRecords = TextRecord::where('id', 'IN', array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))->get();
$language->texts()->insert($textRecords);
```

where `texts()` returns `hasMany('Text')`.

The error returned by laravel is ..

```
Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `ayah_text` (`0`, `1`....
```

I'm not sure why `Laravel` is trying to use block quotes ` instead of ' for values..

Plus, it seems to be inserting new records instead of updating existing ..

Comment: So, basically, `Language` has many `Text`s, right? In your example, you want to attach the `Text`s with ID 1 to 7 to your `Language` with ID 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$language->texts()->associate($textRecords);`

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 4 use whereIn method

```
$textRecords = TextRecord::whereIn('id', array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Child.php

```
public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class);
}
```

Parent.php

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany(Child::class);
}
```

Update foreign key:

```
// updates $child->parent_id
$parent = Parent::find($your_id);
$child->parent()->associate($parent);
$child->save();
```

More info: https://meigwilym.com/family-fortunes-saving-and-updating-laravel-relations/